# Make Android build variants with different package and application id

Tags: android, android-studio

Dears I want to make every build variant with a separated package name and application id because i need to upload app to google play testing env but i can't becuase of it's have project same package for published app on store

Answer (score 4):

you don't need to change the package name, you can add a suffix to each variant like this in app/build.gradle:

```
    debug {
        ...
        applicationIdSuffix = ".debug"
    }
    anotherFlavor {
        ...
        applicationIdSuffix = ".another"
    }
```

or you can change the application id like this :

```
debug {
  applicationId "com.app.debug"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In app/build.gradle, you setup

```
productFlavors {
    dev {
        dimension 'api'
        applicationId "com.abc.dev"
        targetSdkVersion 29
    }
    production {
        dimension 'api'
        applicationId "com.abc"
        targetSdkVersion 29
    }
}
```

Refer: [enter link description here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants)